# Formatting the csv(excel) cells in php

Tags: php, excel, csv, format

Is there any way to format the cells of a csv file with php ? For instance , i have a csv file that i need to format its cell's size before i export it.And another thing is that for numbers with many digits,the excel shows it in another format before i dobule click it and i want to get rid of this too.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
```

I know that i have to show what i have already tried,but i couldn't find any information about this,so i have nowhere to begin...

**EDIT:** The file is csv but i use it as an excel file,and the excel cells are the ones that need to be formated

Comment: Main question: you want a CSV or an excel generated?

Comment: @Naruto , since i use those headers i think its a csv,but i open it with excel,and the excel cells are the ones that i want to be formated with php

Comment: Well what do YOU want in the end? A CSV file (just a file where values are seperated? Or an excel, where you can see the values better than in a csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV format consists of nothing more than raw values; there is no way of storing formatting or data type information. Which is why most, if not all, spreadsheet apps let the user manually set column types when importing a CSV file.

If you want to spare your users the hassle of doing that, your best bet would be generating an xls/xlsx rather than CSV. [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is a popular PHP library for generating Excel files, you might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer was written in 2014, the PHPExcel library has been abandoned. It's last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. It was officially deprecated in 2017 and [permanently archived](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) in 2019. It's direct successor is [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

PHP can parse a CSV string into an array by using `str_getcsv` (http://php.net/str_getcsv). From there it's simply a matter of editing the values of the array.

As for more advanced features, the CSV format in itself does not support them since it's a pure text format and neither PHP nor the CSV file can decide how Excel should parse the file.

I've had success with exporting Excel XML files (the old, pure text XML files; not the new, zipped ones) and if data presentation is important for you, this might be the way to go.